# "openssl"] is not a valid attribute name: .git/info/attributes:5

Tags: git, gitattributes

I am getting following error when setting attributes in `.git/info/attributes` file.

```
$ git add --dry-run . 
"openssl"] is not a valid attribute name: .git/info/attributes:5
"openssl"] is not a valid attribute name: .git/info/attributes:8
add '.gitignore'
add 'README.md'
```

Content of file:

```
* filter=openssl diff=openssl

[merge]
        renormalize=true
[filter "openssl"]
        smudge=~/.gitencrypt/smudge_filter_openssl
        clean=~/.gitencrypt/clear_filter_openssl
[diff   "openssl"]
        textconv=~/.gitencrpt/diff_filter_openssl
```

**Updated:**

```
$ git version
git version 1.8.3.2
```

Comment: The `[merge]`, `[filter ...]` and `[diff ...]` stuff doesn't go in your `.git/info/attributes` file. It goes in `.git/config` or in `${HOME}/.gitconfig`. Read the descriptions of the two types of files using `git help gitattributes` and `git help config`.

Answer (score 5):

For other users, here is another reason wy someone might get a
`is not a valid attributes name .gitattributes:2` error message.

***The number after the colon is the offending line number in your .gitattributes file.***
regardelss fo the specific fix,
this is the line that .gitattributes does not understand,
ie 'xxx is not a valid attribute name..'

In my answer the first character in the message is a 'space'
In the poster's message it was '"openssl"]'

**ERROR MESSAGE:**
`is not a valid attribute name: .gitattributes:2`

**CAUSE:**
  You're setting an attribute value,
    but you've put spaces around the equals sign. 
    Just remove the spaces!

**SOLUTION:**
  Instead of:
    `.htaccess merge = ours`
  Consider:
    `.htaccess merge=ours`

**SYMPTOM:**
  You add a new gitattributes file or line and
     run git status, and
     receive this error or similar:
   is not a valid attribute name: .gitattributes:1

**WHY YOU MAY HAVE THIS IN YOUR FILE:**
  [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_description) incorrectly published examples with spaces around the equals sign.
 It should not have.

**REFERENCE:**
http://www.stegriff.co.uk/upblog/gitattributes-error-is-not-a-valid-attribute-name

This fixed the error in my file.
Obviously the poster's file had a different problem/solution
This is added for other users to know about other possible fixes to a similar error message.